# SparkML alternative to vector assembler

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

I have a logistic regression sparkml pipeline where one of the stages is to combine unigrams, bigrams, and trigrams. Currently, I'm combining them by using vector assembler. 
Vector assembler seems to be very expensive and is increasing my prediction time three-fold. Any ideas ?

```
val unigram = new NGram().setN(1).setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("unigram")
val hashingTFunigram = new HashingTF().setInputCol(unigram.getOutputCol).setOutputCol("tfFeatures").setNumFeatures(5000)

val bigram = new NGram().setN(2).setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("bigram")
val hashingTFbigram = new HashingTF().setInputCol(bigram.getOutputCol).setOutputCol("tfFeaturesbigram").setNumFeatures(5000)

val trigram = new NGram().setN(3).setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("trigram")
val hashingTFtrigram = new HashingTF().setInputCol(trigram.getOutputCol).setOutputCol("tfFeaturestrigram").setNumFeatures(5000)

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("tfFeaturesunigram", "tfFeaturesbigram", "tfFeaturestrigram"))
  .setOutputCol("tfFeatures")
```